# error messages in ES6 class instantiation

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

After years of using JavaScript, I am about to write my first JS class (!). What I'd like to do is to throw an error if a required constructor parameter is not provided. Kinda like so

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);

        if (!(this.reqd = options.reqd)) {
            return 'error: 'reqd' is required'
        }

        this.optional = options.optional;
    }
}
```

`const f = new Foo({optional: 'frob'})` would throw an error, but `const f = new Foo({reqd: 'blub'})` or `const f = new Foo({reqd: 'blub', optional: 'frob'})` would work.

Can this be done?

Comment: It works exactly like a traditional constructor function. If you can do it there you can do it here. Yes, it can be done. But, please consider throwing a custom exception rather than returning something that may not make sense contextually.

Comment: I think you mean for your constructor to `throw` the error string rather than `return` the error string.  If a constructor doesn't return an object, then the object returned by `new` will be as if the constructor returned `this`.  But if the constructor **does** return an object, then that object is used as the object for `new`.  Returning a string **does not count** as returning an object; it simply doesn't cause an error or an exception.  Not sure if you understand this or if it's just a typo in your example.

Comment: @Wyck you are absolutely correct. And your final suspicion also is correct – That `return` was not a typo, I actually didn't know how to do this (until now, on reading @CertainPerformance's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the `options` object has a `reqd` property with `hasOwnProperty`, and if it doesn't, throw an error:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(options) {
        // super(options);
        if (!options.hasOwnProperty('reqd')) {
          throw new Error('reqd property is required');
        }
        this.reqd = options.reqd;
        // if you don't want to assign `undefined` for a non-existent optional property,
        // use a hasOwnProperty check before assigning
        this.optional = options.optional;
    }
}

const f1 = new Foo({ reqd: 'val' });
console.log('next');
const f2 = new Foo({ optional: 'val' });
```

If you want an error to be thrown, you have to explicitly `throw` it, else there won't be an error (or, at least not until later). Just returning a string is not erroneous.

Comment: The notion of doing `throw new Error('my error string')` instead of `return 'my error string'` is a critical detail.